# How can we trigger a stateful widget to rebuild itself with navigation using Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When we navigate to different pages in Flutter using a BottomNavigationBar, stateful pages don't seem to rebuild themselves.

This means that we cannot trigger rebuilding a stateful widget using BottomNavigationBar, unlike a Drawer. The state remains as is, the BottomNavigationBar slides over pages and does not help with rebuilding the whole page again.

```dart
int _selectedIndex = 0;
static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  Page1(),
  Page2(),
  Page3(),
];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    ),
    body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```

Here the widgets namely `Page1()`, `Page2()`, `Page3()` are stateful widgets, they don't seem to rebuild themselves when navigated by the bottom navigation bar. Is there any way we could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  Page1(),
  Page2(),
  Page3(),
];
```

Use

```
Widget _widgetOptions(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return Page1();
      break;
    case 1:
      return Page2();
      break;
    case 2:
      return Page3();
      break;
  }
  return Page1();
}
```

And also replace

```
body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
```

with

```
body: _widgetOptions(_selectedIndex),
```